# Prove set is bounded and nonempty?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a function $f(x, y) = 1-x^2-y^2$ and I have the set $A = f^{-1}([C, \infty)$. I need to show that it is compact. I have already shown that it is closed but I'm not sure how to show it is bounded. Also for small C, how do I show A is nonempty?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\begin{align*}
A=f^{-1}([C,\infty))&=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:f(x,y)\in[C,\infty)\}\\
&=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:1-x^2-y^2\geq C\}\\
&=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq1-C\}
\end{align*}$$
is the closed disk of radius $\sqrt{1-C}$ centered at the origin when $C\leq 1$, and empty when $C>1$. Now you can easily show directly that a closed disk is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Para C>1 the set is empty, C=1 is single point and for C<1 is a disc of raius $\sqrt{1-C}$

$1-x^{2}-y^{2}\geq C \implies x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1- C $